# Does placement-new into the same type still require to manually call the destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, placement-new

***Context***

I'm trying to get a grasp on the placement-new mechanism since I never have had to use it. I'm trying to understand how to properly use it out of pure curiosity.

For the question, we will consider the following code base for illustration purposes:

```
struct Pack
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    Pack() = default;
    Pack(int w, int x, int y, int z) : a(w), b(x), c(y), d(z)
    {}
    ~Pack()
    {
        std::cout << "Destroyed\n";
    }
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Pack & p)
{
    os << '[' << p.a << ", " << p.b << ", " << p.c << ", " << p.d << ']';
    return os;
}
```

Basically it just defines a structure holding some data (4 integers in the example), and I overloaded the `operator<<()` to simplify the code in the testing part.

I know that when using placement-new, one has to manually call the destructor of the object because we can't use `delete` since we only want to destroy the object (and not to free the memory since it was already allocated).

Example **(A)**:

```
char b[sizeof(Pack)];
Pack * p = new (b) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4);
std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<Pack*>(b) << '\n';

p->~Pack();
```

***Question***

I was wondering, when using placement-new into an object of the same type, is it still necessary to call the destructor of the object ?

Example **(B)**:

```
Pack p;
new (&p) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4);
std::cout << p << '\n';
```

I did a quick [test of both version here](https://godbolt.org/z/rrf3o7zzY) and it seems that the destructor is properly called when the underlying object goes out of scope while being of type `Pack`.
I know it's stupid to use placement-new in such a trivial example instead of directly creating the object. But in a real-case example, it can be a buffer or `Pack` instead of a buffer of `char`.

I would like to know if I am right to assume that I don't need to manually call the destructor in the example **(B)** or if I'm missing something.

---

***Extra***

As a subsidiary question, in the example **(A)**, is it legal to get rid of the returned pointer and call the destructor through the `reinterpret_cast`ed pointer instead ?

For example can it be rewritten like this:

```
char b[sizeof(Pack)];
new (b) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4);
std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<Pack*>(b) << '\n';

reinterpret_cast<Pack*>(b)->~Pack(); // Is it legal ?
```

It would be useful in the case I have a buffer of objects and I want to destroy its elements without having to keep the returned pointers somewhere.

***[Disclaimer]***: Of course, in a real case program, I would use a `std::vector` and the `emplace_back()` function instead of my own buffer. As already mentioned, this question is purely out of curiosity, just to understand how it's meant to work under the hood.

Comment: In general, **yes**, you need to explicitly call the destructor in that situation.  (With some exceptions to the rule, such as when POD is involved.)

Comment: About the extra section. No, `b` might "point" to the old or no object because of some complicated C++ rules, see `std::launder` which is related to this. Therefore it is better to always use the pointer returned from `new`.

Comment: In the live example test case (1) the code has created 2 objects in `p` ( `Pack p;` and then the placement new object ) __but__ has destroyed only 1 of them. There needs to 2 instances of the destructor being called unless `p` is trivial.

Comment: @RichardCritten But if I rewrite my example with a structure that manages dynamically allocated resources, trying to manually call the destructor causes a [double deletion](https://godbolt.org/z/cejWzTd6W).

Comment: @Fareanor You should destroy `p` before replacing it with the placement new - live - https://godbolt.org/z/58f6h3jsP  If you don't any memory allocated by `p` will leak as the placement new overwrites it's internal state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you must call the destructor. It's irrelevant whether the old object is of same type or not.

Only thing that matters is whether the type of the old object is trivially destructible. If it is, then there is no need to call the destructor. If it isn't, then you must call the destructor before reusing the memory.

Example:

```
Pack p;

new (&p) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4); // Not OK

p.~Pack();
new (&p) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4); // OK
```

Note that there are cases where this isn't allowed such as if the class contains const qualified members or reference members. In general, I recommend avoiding such pattern, and to instead re-use only arrays of char or similar trivial storage.

> As a subsidiary question, in the example (A), is it legal to get rid of the returned pointer and call the destructor through the reinterpret_casted pointer instead ?

Just like all uses of the placement-newed object, you can reintepret the addresss of the original object, but you must launder it:

```
Pack* ptr = new (b) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4);

std::cout << *ptr << '\n'; // OK
std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<Pack*>(b) << '\n'; // Not OK
std::cout << *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Pack*>(b)) << '\n'; // OK

ptr->~Pack(); // OK
reinterpret_cast<Pack*>(b)->~Pack(); // Not OK
std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Pack*>(b))->~Pack(); // OK
```

---

> ```
> char b[sizeof(Pack)];
> Pack * p = new (b) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4);
> ```

This is wrong. You must ensure that the storage is properly aligned for the placement-newed type:

```
alignas(alignof(Pack)) char b[sizeof(Pack)];
```

Comment: If, for example, the object manages dynamically allocated resources that must be released in the destructor, do I need to manually call the destructor even if the object if of the same type ? I'm asking this because in my godbolt example,  the destructor seems to be already automatically called and I want to avoid double deletion in that case.

Comment: not sure but i think op is asking whether the placement-newed object needs to be destroyed by calling the destructor and they correctly observe that its not the case (when created in memory of the `Pack p;`). And If I correctly understand the answer, you are saying that the old object should be destroyed before the new is created in its place. Not sure if its me or the answer can be clarified. Sometimes I am a little slow ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Is it clearer now?

Comment: not sure. `Pack p; new (&p) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4);` is ok? No need to destruct the initial `p` manually?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's not OK. As I said, *"you must call the destructor."*

Comment: But if my structure manages dynamically allocated resources, when I call the destructor in the case **(B)**, I get a double deletion error as you can [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/cejWzTd6W). Did I miss something ?

Comment: yeah but I think OP is only worried about deleting the placement-newed `p` in their Example `B`. As my understanding goes now B should be `Pack p; b.~Pack(); new (p) Pack(1,2,3,4); /* destructor will be called when p goes out of scope to destruct the placement new-ed p*/`.

Comment: @Fareanor You must destroy the automatic variable **before** the placement new. Not after.

Comment: In that case, I get an invalid pointer error [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/EnK9eersr). I'm starting to think there really is something I did not understand about placement-new. I thought it was to construct an object in-place in an already allocated memory space.

Comment: @Fareanor That's because your default constructor fails to initialise the pointer that the destructor deletes.

Comment: @Fareanor In your example you do `Pack p;` and then `p.~Pack();` which causes you to call `delete` on the `e` member even though your default constructor didn't allocate any memory for it.  That's why you get an error.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot I kept the defaulted one.... my bad

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. Learned something today

Answer (score 1):

Not calling a destructor is *not* undefined behaviour. But it could lead to undefined behaviour if you rely on the side effects of the destructor.

In your example (a), there are two `Pack` objects created. One is default constructed at `Pack p;`. The lifetime of this object ends when you reuse its storage with `new (b) Pack(1, 2, 3, 4);`, starting the lifetime of a different `Pack` object at the same address, which ends with an explicit call to the destructor. Note that there are 2 constructors called but only 1 destructor. If this class held some resources (like a `std::vector` or `std::string`), it could lead to a memory leak, but that is not UB in itself.

If the destructor was trivial, there are no side effects, so skipping the destructor call will always be OK.

Comment: Thanks you for the clarification, I forgot I kept the defaulted constructor of my previous example, I'm so stupid :D